# Dovecot auth failed “missing args”

Tags: email, dovecot

I try to config Dovecot and I got this strange log:

```
Sep 14 23:02:02 hostname dovecot: auth: Fatal: passdb passwd-file: Missing args
Sep 14 23:02:02 hostname dovecot: master: Error: service(auth): command startup failed, throttling for 16 secs
Sep 14 23:02:02 hostname dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected: Auth process broken (disconnected before auth was ready, waited 0 secs): user=<>, rip=77.124.48.11, lip=31.220.109.9, session=<nWjpEYM8vgBNfC8L>
```

by the way here is the format of the passwd file I tried to use to store the usernames and passwords:

```
user:{plain}pass
```

and here is the auth-system.conf.ext file:

```
    # Authentication for passwd-file users. Included from 10-auth.conf.
#
# passwd-like file with specified location.
# <doc/wiki/AuthDatabase.PasswdFile.txt>

passdb {
  driver = passwd-file
  args = scheme=PLAIN username_format=/etc/maillpass
}

userdb {
  driver = passwd-file
  args = username_format=/etc/maillpass

  # Default fields that can be overridden by passwd-file
  #default_fields = quota_rule=*:storage=1G

  # Override fields from passwd-file
  #override_fields = home=/home/virtual/%u
}
```

by the way yes, it is /etc/mail**l**pass

can someone see the problem?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have an issue in the `args` lines.

```
args = scheme=PLAIN username_format=/etc/maillpass
args = username_format=/etc/maillpass
```

Dovecot expects the last argument to be the file to be loaded, you're assigning the filename to the `username_format` parameter instead. If you do not need a `username_format` pattern, use `args` lines like

```
args = scheme=PLAIN /etc/maillpass
args = /etc/maillpass
```

The options are described in the [AuthDatabase/PasswordFile](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/AuthDatabase/PasswdFile) sections in the Dovecot wiki.